# Twig create link with variable

Tags: plugin-development, templating

I would like to create a link to another page in my plugin and send a specific ID with it but I don't really know how to do it in craft and twig.. I spend too much time on that little task and searched in the internet but could not really find something.

In my template I have

```
//loop through all database entries
{% for val in entries %}
    .....
    <a href="{{ url('pluginName/editEntry/' + val.id) }}">Edit</a>
    .....
{% endfor %}
```

But it does not really work. How can I pass a specific id in my url and how can I receive this parameter in my php backend?
I didn't find something like `craft()->request->getGetVar()`and my `$_GET` is always empty. Of course I could just take the URL and use subtring and explode to get the correct value but I'm not sure if this is the intended way

Answer (score 4):

Use the `~` symbol to concat strings.

```
//loop through all database entries
{% for val in entries %}
    .....
    <a href="{{ url('pluginName/editEntry/' ~ val.id) }}">Edit</a>
    .....
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you, could you tell me if there is a better way to get the id in php except `craft()->request->getUrl();` and exploding the string?

Comment: There is a a cheat sheet: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/cheat-sheet-craft.request .   Maybe `craft->request->getSegment(n);`

Comment: I already saw that but I don't know how to use it... getSegment is always null... seems like I'll just use the substring method